# When installing Pipfile there is a collision of dependency version of werkzeug, werkzeug<1.0 from zappa, werkzeug>2.0 from flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, python-zappa

When installing the Pipfile i'm getting the error 'ERROR: Could not find a version that matches werkzeug<1.0,>=2.0'

There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
werkzeug<1.0 (from zappa==0.51.0)
werkzeug>=2.0 (from flask==2.0.1)

MY Pipfile contains (among other stuff):

```
flask = "*"
werkzeug = "*"
zappa = "*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your zappa version is 0.51.0 which was released on March 2020 and your flask version is 2.0.1 which was released on May 2021 and their sub dependencies are different.
I fixed the issue by downgrading the flask version by specifying version 1.1.4 in pipfile.
flask = "==1.1.4"

Answer (score 1):

For poetry users, this is what I did (after doing a remove of flask 2.0):

```
   $ poetry add flask@1.1.4
```